# is safe to use AWS ElasticBeanstalk for background tasks? (no front accesible via HTTP)

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a nodejs app to my AWS EB instance (with MySQL inside EB too), but my nodejs is not creating any server, is just a background task: couple of websockets that I want to keep connected 24/7 to save data in mysql.
It seems to be working, but maybe is not safe to do that, because AWS is showing some warnings, it says the http requestes are not working. Which is obvious but not sure if could be a side effect, I want to be sure my nodejs+mysql app will be running 24/7 forever.

Comment: What does Elastic Beanstalk buy you that an EC2 doesn't?  Failover?  If you're not using the monitoring then it seems that might be the only reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally safe to do that.

My guess is that the warning you see it's because Beanstalk is trying to guess if your environment is healthy or not.

Maybe you can expose an endpoint that returns 200 OK and set up the monitoring to check that URL.

Another way, not recommended, it's to disable the monitoring.